# After updating Xcode and VisualStudioForMac app is not working

Tags: macos, xamarin, nsurlconnection, ios12

After updating Xcode and VS for Mac my app is not working on ios 12.
It gives me an error that my **NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100**.
my app is built with xamarin on mac.
I tried to change  some options in NSAppTransportSecurity, but it doesn't help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have some html files in your project?

Comment: Yes. I am working with ionic v1 and using web viewer in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edit your Info.Plist file with:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: No it doesn't help. Maybe here is a bug in new ver of xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error by following below steps:

```
1) Delete node modules,plugins folder
2) ionic cordova platform remove ios
3) npm install
4) ionic cordova platform add ios
5) ionic cordova build ios
```